# How do I convert string value to a date format

Tags: c#

```
string strDateFrom;
string strDateTo;

CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue DateValue = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterDiscreteValue();

if ((strDateFrom != "") && (strDateTo != ""))      
{                                      
    DateValue.Value = "(From: " + strDateFrom + " - " + strDateTo + ")";
}     
else     
{
    DateValue.Value = "(ALL DATES)";    
}
```

Comment: Check `DateTime.Parse` method

Comment: What's the format of `strDateFrom` and `strDateTo`? That's going to be important.

Comment: The format is in 'mm/dd/yy'. Its a format derived from the database through a stored procedured

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse)

```
string date = "2020-02-02";
    DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(date);
    Console.WriteLine(time);
```

Or [use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e.aspx):

```
DateTime oDate = DateTime.Parse(string s);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid formatting issue, I prefer using `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

basically the difference between those methods and  `DateTime.Parse` is weather you know the date format of the string (and then you use  `DateTime.ParseExact`) or not (and then use `DateTime.Parse`).

You can read more about [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT**:
Example code from the links:

```
 string dateString, format;  
      DateTime result;
      CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

      // Parse date-only value with invariant culture.
      dateString = "06/15/2008";
      format = "d";
      try {
         result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
         Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
      }
      catch (FormatException) {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
      } 

      // Parse date-only value without leading zero in month using "d" format.
      // Should throw a FormatException because standard short date pattern of  
      // invariant culture requires two-digit month.
      dateString = "6/15/2008";
      try {
         result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
         Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
      }
      catch (FormatException) {
         Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
      }
```

Comment: A bit different from the example a I gave, will try it out

Answer (score 0):

If you *know the format* used, you can try `DateTime.ParseExact()` or `DateTime.TryParseExact()`:

```
  String text = "30/12/2013"; 

  DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```